# Weapon Rotation Three.js

Tags: graphics, three.js

I need to rotate a mesh "cylinder_weapon" for a trivial game by using Three.js. The problem is that the weapon follow the movements of the player but when I rotate the visual the position of the weapon stays static.

```
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//      render the scene                        //
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
updateFcts.push(function(){

var time = Date.now() * 0.0005;

    renderer.render( scene, camera );
controls.update(clock.getDelta());
castRays();

cylinder_weapon.position.set(
        camera.position.x - Math.sin(camera.rotation.y + Math.PI/6) * 0.75+1,
        camera.position.y - 0.5 + Math.sin(time*4 + camera.position.x + camera.position.z)*0.01,
        camera.position.z + Math.cos(camera.rotation.y + Math.PI/6) * 0.75);

cylinder_weapon.rotation.set(
                               camera.rotation.x,
                               camera.rotation.y - Math.PI,
                               camera.rotation.z
                                                    );
               })
```

[Here is an example of what I need](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f5B5n.png)

Does anyone got any hint ?

Comment: _but when I rotate the visual the position of the weapon stays static_ Could you explain this? Or add some explanatory pics? Or a live code example?

Comment: Yes you are right , I added a pic of a gun that works like I need. The idea is that if I move the camera with the mouse the gun stays in the same position (on the right side of the camera ,like classic FPS)

Comment: Adding this as a comment because I don't feel it's worth a full answer... Add the "weapon" to the **camera**, and position it with the understanding that the camera looks down its -Z axis. It seems counter-intuitive, but three.js will view the camera as just another container in its search for renderable items.

Comment: Ok and how could I add it to the camera ? It is a mesh object , is there any function in order to do this ?

Comment: Most objects--including the camera--are based on `Object3D`, which is where the `add` method comes from. It will work exactly how you expect: `yourCamera.add(someObject);`